# Negative SKlearn linear regression score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to build a house price prediction model with sklearn linear regression and I am getting a negative score.

Please what am I doing wrong?

dataset:

[this is the dataset](https://github.com/Ubanna/house_data)

Screenshot of Dataset:
[image]

Please see below details:

Shape of dataframe:
(23435, 190)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

    properties_five = pd.read_csv('house_test.csv')
    
    X = properties_five.drop('price', axis='columns')
    y = properties_five['price']
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
    
    lr_clf = LinearRegression()
    lr_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(lr_clf.score(X_train,y_train))
    print(lr_clf.score(X_test,y_test))
    
    cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    
    print(cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), X, y, cv=cv))
```

score on training data: 0.0025884591059242013

score on test data : -1.6566338615525985e+24

Comment: Please share your code output

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question with this

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine - except the line `df = pd.read_csv('house_test.csv')` should probably be `properties_five = pd.read_csv('house_test.csv')` to match the next lines.

When I run it on [this data set](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/therbootcamp/ML_2019Oct/master/1_Data/house_test.csv), I get the following output:

```
0.7307587542204755
0.465770160153375
[0.64358885 0.67211318 0.67817097 0.53631898 0.67390831]
```

Perhaps the linear regression simply performs poorly on your data set, or else your data set contains errors. A negative R² score means that you would be better off using "constant regression", that is having your prediction be always equal to the mean of `y`.

Comment: I also tried on another dataset and got a positive score, I think the issue is with my dataset. I have updated my question with a link to the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Please share your outputs. Also linear regression is subject to outliers so you should standardize the numerical variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have read the file using `df` name, so the very next line you should replace `properties_five` with `df`. And try to standardize/normalize the dataset, I hope that it will help to reduce error, [for example here you can find details](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html).

Comment: I also tried on another dataset and got a positive score, I think the issue is with my dataset. I have updated my question with a link to the dataset

Comment: That means linear regression is not suitable for your data. This method tries to fit a straight line, but if there is a complex non-linear relation between target and independent variables, then you need to choose a non-linear model. -ve score means your model is performing really poorly there. If you see the mathematical equation that how the score is calculated over there, you will get the intuition behind this. I will suggest to use non-linear models.